Can I lubricate the idler wheel shaft of my dryer while I wait for my new part to get here?
I have a squeaky dryer and have determined it's the wheel on the pulley. I've ordered the part but it will take a week to get here.
Is there some way I can lubricate it so it isn't squealing while I wait? Just as a temporary fix?

Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn why the comments above are not answers to your question, and how to respond to answers.

You certainly can. I did just that and gained a few months of silence until I got around to replacing the wheels. Fresh bearings last much longer than oil on old bearings.
Use a household oil or light motor oil (5w or 10w), not WD-40. In a pinch use whatever viscous, non-decaying substance you have on hand, like vegetable or baby oil.

I did take it. I didn't see where it said not to say thanks. I'll refrain from this in the future though!
